# Ajax reloading is not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

jQuery DataTables Ajax reloading is not working:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
   "bProcessing": true,
   "bServerSide": true,
   "sAjaxSource": "check-request.php",
   "aoColumns": [
      {mData: 'email'},
      {mData: 'mob'},
      {mData: 'date'}
   ]
} );

setInterval( function () {
   table.ajax.reload();
}, 3000 );
```

Comment: format code. its not readable at all

Comment: Why is this tagged only PHP while it's clearly JavaScript / DataTables ?

Comment: `sAjaxSource` is v1.9 syntax, `table.ajax.reload()` is v1.10.  I'm not saying that's the problem, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to just have the table reload every three seconds?

Comment: You have a mix of clientside processing and serverside processing settings. `table.ajax.reload()` is for clientside processing, but you have `bServerSide` set to `true`.  Set `bServerSide` to false or dont set it at all.